# What happens when I poke someone?

Tags: subway-surfers

Some of the challenges (Daily and for the spray cans) require poking friends. What happens when I poke a friend?

- Does it show up on Facebook like a regular poke (does this feature even still exist on Facebook?)?
- Does it show up on Facebook as one of those annoying app invites?
- Does it only show up in the Subway Surfers app?
- Nothing?

I'd rather not bombard my "friends" (mostly people I knew in school I haven't talked to in like 10 years) with obnoxious notifications, so I'd like to know what this does before I go around poking everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen. Just that the app registers your poking for the quest and one of the awards.